# Looking for a specific Twilight Zone-style comic storyline - Wealthiest man in the world, global ecological disaster, cryogenically frozen

Tags: story-identification, comics, speed-of-light, cryogenics

I remember reading a comic book in a flea market, about thirty years ago (meaning I read it in the mid-1980s, though the comic book was likely dated from the early 1970s to the early 1980s), that had a particular Twilight Zone/Tales from the Crypt/Astounding Stories style twist to it.

The focus of the storyline involved the wealthiest man in the world.  The rest of the world was living in abject poverty, and the world itself was on the edge of ecological disaster (due to his global business enterprises).  Even though he owned most of the world and controlled the world leadership (of sorts), he confronts a scientist and makes out a check for an obscene amount of money.  As it turns out, he wants the scientist to create a device that can cryogenically freeze him so he can awaken on a future date (100 years, or so) and reap the benefits of his investments that would keep growing while he is frozen.  The scientist balks at first, and suggests the money would be better spent helping the world avert global catastrophe.

But the wealthy man insists upon it.  End of the story?  The scientist creates this sort of 'cryogenic crypt', the man is frozen and wakes up about 100 years or so in the future.  He emerges from the crypt, nearly choking, only to discover the planet enshrouded in toxic clouds.  Humanity had long since left the planet, in search of a new host world, as the scientist had taken a bulk of the money to develop a fleet of faster-than-light spacecraft.  Leaving the 'wealthiest' man in the world the only man left on a dead planet.  Any idea of what this might have been?